# Why are up votes not showing on the question?

Tags: discussion, voting

When a question (of mine) gets upvoted, I get the points added to "reputation" but they don't show up next to the question as a +. Why is that? Sorry but your website does not have a comprehensive page explaining how the point system works. Thank you.

Comment: Which question are you talking about?  Your [profile](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/27487/daisy?tab=questions) indicates that you have no non-deleted questions.

Comment: Now it's there. Weird. Is there a page that specifically shows how many points + and - for this that or the other? Thank you

Comment: There's this: http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation

Comment: Helpful link -thanks

Comment: I've found that sometimes the system does not update various events immediately everywhere in the system. It's possible that if you wait a few hours, everything will show up as it should.

Comment: @LeeWoofenden, that makes sense. By the way, I like your name. Sounds like a wolf in a den. I used to have a wolf dog so your name makes me smile.

Comment: Haha! Way back when my father and mother (now deceased) were a pastor and pastor's wife, one of the elderly church ladies made up a little parlor game in which she gave clues for the names of each of the ladies in the women's sewing circle, for the others to guess. The clue for my mother's name was, "bark in a small room." :-)

Comment: That's cute! I bet those women made some great stuff in their circle. I have a machine but I don't have the patience. I love dogs, I love wolves, I love animals. :o)

Answer (score 1):

Please read each of the articles under [Reputation & Moderation](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help/reputation) in the help section as well as review [this FAQ post on the main SE meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/145951). These posts detail everything that can happen to reputation numbers and why.

Some specific points you might have missed:

1. Voting on posts in the per-site metas (like the one your are on now) do not affect reputation. Reputation points are calculated from activity on the main sites only.
2. If 1 person upvotes a post and 1 other downvotes it, the number show next to the post will be 0, but you will earn the +5 (question) or +10 (answer) points and loose the -2 from the downvote. The [reputation activity in your profile](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/27487/daisy?tab=reputation&sort=post) lists exactly what has happened that affects your rep.

Comment: #2 isn't always working; that's my point. The down votes don't always show as an activity on my profile but they'll show as a negative next to a question or an answer. That's what happened yesterday when I first wrote and then when I went back to the page, it was gone (it was fixed somehow) so I couldn't tell Nathaniel which question it was. I haven't gone through all of them to see if it's happening again but next time I notice it, I'll photograph the page so you guys can see what I'm talking about. A negative next to a Q or A and nothing recorded on the profile (no negative red number).

Comment: When you wrote "reputation activity in your profile" --do you have access to that profile where you can see what I up and down voted? If I click on someone's name, I don't find that anywhere. Does everyone have access to what others are up and down voting?

Comment: @Daisy Other users do not have access to which posts users are voting on.  However, the [reputation tab of your profile](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/27487/daisy?tab=reputation) will show you which posts of yours were upvoted and downvoted, by day.

Comment: hi Nathaniel, so people can't see eachother's reputation tabs that show up and down votes?

Comment: @Daisy People can see exactly what you can see: what posts are getting voted on is public but who is doing the voting is private, even moderators can't see who is voting on what. Look at your own and other people's profiles and you'll know exactly what other people can see.